# jquery, issue with .animate()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, position

Inside a div #frame I have 3 others div: #top, #middle and #bottom. #top and #bottom are in display none, and when the mouse is over #frame, with the jquery function animate, the height of #frame is increasing and #top and #bottom are showing. When the mouse is out #frame, the size of #frame is decreasing and #top and #bottom are going away.

my css are:

```
#frame{
    position: absolute;
    left:200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    top:200px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

#middle{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
}

#top{
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
}

#bottom{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
}
```

my HTML:

```
<div id="frame">
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="middle">middle</div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom<br>bottom<br>bottom<br>bottom</div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#frame', function( e ) {
    var el = $(this),
        h = el.height(),
        t = el.offset().top,
        mEnt = e.type == "mouseenter";
    if(mEnt == true){
        $('#top').stop().fadeIn(300);
        $('#bottom').stop().fadeIn(300);
        $('#middle').stop().animate({'top':'20px'});
        el.stop().animate({
            'height':h+$('#bottom').height()+20,
            'top':t-20
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#top').stop().fadeOut(300);
        $('#bottom').stop().fadeOut(300);
        $('#middle').stop().animate({'top':'0px'});
        el.stop().animate({
            'height':200,
            'top':t+20
        });
    }
});
```

I made a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/N7mhp/

My issue is when I'm entering and leaving #frame really fast its position is changing.

I think it comes from the variable t which its value is changing at the same time as the position of #frame so how can I "freeze" the value of t to the first position of #frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var t;
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#frame', function( e ) {
    var el = $(this),
        h = el.height(),
        mEnt = e.type == "mouseenter";
    if(t == null) t = el.offset().top;
```